# Making a sentence that can only contain the characters inside an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sanitize requests in HTML. My approach is to make it so the sentence's characters can only be the same characters as in the array.

It just blocks all inputs :/

This is my code:

```js
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPassword.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  input = email + pass;

  console.log(input)
  if (input === null) {
    return document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML = "Sorry, Something went wrong."
  }
  var allowedCharacters = ["_", ".", "@", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", 'L', "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var allowedNumbers = 1 - 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;

  var allowedC = allowedCharacters.toString()
  if (input !== allowedC.(input)) {
    return document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML = "Error Code 4081: <a target='_blank' href='https://liamassistant.web.app/errors'><font color='black'>Learn More</font></a>"
  }

  // if (input === allowedCharacters && allowedNumbers) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
      return document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML = "That Account is Already Registered.";
    }
    if (!firebaseUser) {
      const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,
        pass);
      promise.catch(e => {
        console.log(e.message)
        document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML = "We Couldn't Create Your Account. That Account Me Be Already Registered."
      })
    }
  })
  // }
})
```

Comment: What is `var allowedNumbers = 1 - 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
` supposed to do?

Comment: Hey,

This is to allow numbers. I just excluded the variable from the if statement whilst debugging.

Comment: It is not valid JS. The number `-99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` does not exist. It is not a range if you think it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression instead: in a character set, you can match alphabetical characters with `a-z` (case insensitive), and numbers with `\d`. Put your other permitted characters into the character set, and you get:

```
/[_.@a-z\d]/i
```

Negate that character set, and you'll match any characters which are in the input but are *not* one of the allowed characters:

```
if (/[^_.@a-z\d]/i.test(input)) {
  // Invalid characters were provided, display error
}
```

You can also switch `_a-z\d_` with `\w`, they're equivalent:

```
if (/[^\w.@]/i.test(input)) {
  // Invalid characters were provided, display error
}
```